# Setting application info in a Qt executable file on Windows

Tags: windows, resources, qt4, version, versioninfo

Anyone have an tips on setting the application info (ie. right click on .exe->properties) from Qt?

I can add arbitrary version strings to Qt resource file (qrc) and display them. 
But most Windows installers check the version number and I can't find a Qt way of setting these fields other than manually maintaining a separate .RC file

Some way that lets you update this from an automated build would also be nice!

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Here's how I do it... add a file called resources.rc to your project with the contents:

```
IDI_ICON1   ICON    DISCARDABLE "res/app.ico"

#include <windows.h>
#include "version.h"

VS_VERSION_INFO VERSIONINFO
FILEVERSION     VER_FILEVERSION
PRODUCTVERSION  VER_PRODUCTVERSION
BEGIN
    BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        BLOCK "040904E4"
        BEGIN
            VALUE "CompanyName",        VER_COMPANYNAME_STR
            VALUE "FileDescription",    VER_FILEDESCRIPTION_STR
            VALUE "FileVersion",        VER_FILEVERSION_STR
            VALUE "InternalName",       VER_INTERNALNAME_STR
            VALUE "LegalCopyright",     VER_LEGALCOPYRIGHT_STR
            VALUE "LegalTrademarks1",   VER_LEGALTRADEMARKS1_STR
            VALUE "LegalTrademarks2",   VER_LEGALTRADEMARKS2_STR
            VALUE "OriginalFilename",   VER_ORIGINALFILENAME_STR
            VALUE "ProductName",        VER_PRODUCTNAME_STR
            VALUE "ProductVersion",     VER_PRODUCTVERSION_STR
        END
    END

    BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        VALUE "Translation", 0x409, 1252
    END
END
```

and a file called version.h with the contents:

```
#ifndef VERSION_H
#define VERSION_H

#define VER_FILEVERSION             1,0,0,0
#define VER_FILEVERSION_STR         "1.0.0.0\0"

#define VER_PRODUCTVERSION          1,0,0,0
#define VER_PRODUCTVERSION_STR      "1.0\0"

#define VER_COMPANYNAME_STR         "Your Organization"
#define VER_FILEDESCRIPTION_STR     "CoolApplication"
#define VER_INTERNALNAME_STR        "CoolApplication"
#define VER_LEGALCOPYRIGHT_STR      "Copyright © 2010 Your Organization"
#define VER_LEGALTRADEMARKS1_STR    "All Rights Reserved"
#define VER_LEGALTRADEMARKS2_STR    VER_LEGALTRADEMARKS1_STR
#define VER_ORIGINALFILENAME_STR    "coolapplication.exe"
#define VER_PRODUCTNAME_STR         "CoolApplication"

#define VER_COMPANYDOMAIN_STR       "example.org"

#endif // VERSION_H
```

and lastly to your .pro file, add: `RC_FILE = resources.rc`. Non-Windows platforms will ignore the value so you needn't prefix it with `win32:`.

Comment: Thanks - thats still maintaining a separate rc file. I ended up doing something where my python build script just wrote an RC file like this.

Comment: this did not work for me
nothing changed with all this code added to the resource file

Comment: It works great.  Make sure you include any paths to your RC file.

# Windows RC file
RC_FILE = $$PWD/resources/resources.rc

Comment: Where's the documentation for that syntax you used in resources.rc file?

Comment: @Jack: Documentation is here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381058(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I did exactly as you said and it didn't change anything (the version is still 0.0.0.0)

Answer (score 59):

Okay, two years after being asked... but maybe somebody will find it useful...

Try to use the following qmake variables:

```
VERSION = 0.4.0.1
QMAKE_TARGET_COMPANY = company
QMAKE_TARGET_PRODUCT = product
QMAKE_TARGET_DESCRIPTION = description
QMAKE_TARGET_COPYRIGHT = copyright
```

More info [here](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/16520).

Comment: Thanks, haven't tested it because I work in VS, but more answers are always good

Comment: Is there any way to get `VERSION` at runtime with some piece of code?

Comment: See APP_VERSION macro here: http://www.openguru.com/2009/11/qt-best-way-to-set-application-version.html