# Change visible application name (Windows)

Tags: windows, qt4, mingw

I am looking for a way to change my application name (that appears on right click on Windows 7 taskbar):

[image: My Application]

To something more informative like:

[image: ImageShack Uploader]

How do I do that? 
I am using: Qt 4.7 (MinGW), Windows

I have found some info about using certificates and signing executables, but I am not sure if it is what I need. I know how to change icon. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't that just the application's title - which can be changed via `QWidget::setWindowTitle(const QString&)`? (Not entirely sure, therefore comment not answer.)

Comment: No, window title differs from executable name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From 5 minutes of experimentation it seem to be coming from the FileDescription field of the [VERSIONINFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381058.aspx) resource.  It also seems like Windows is caching these values based on filename; I had to rename the .exe file each time I changed the resource for the changes to show up.

Comment: Could you please provide an example what to add to RC file?

Comment: Just add a version information resource through the wizard; it's the easiest way.

Comment: Qt Creator doesn't have any wizards to add Windows version information (at least I haven't found any). And EdgeLuxe is using MinGW so he is probably using Qt Creator instead of Visual Studio.

Comment: @EdgeLuxe: See this question for information about RC file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784697/setting-application-info-in-qt