# a description in a qt exe file

Tags: qt, executable

how do I add the description to my exe file made with qt

the only description that shows is the title of the application

the description type I want is the one in the exe's properties

Comment: Description when you mouse over it?  Or description that you can add within the application in the about/help menus?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "description"? Do you mean the extra information when looking at the exe's properties?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting application info in a Qt executable file on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784697/setting-application-info-in-a-qt-executable-file-on-windows)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean the resource file information under Windows, the following link has some same code for you:

http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/35810-Detail-Information

**Edit:**

Better yet, see this post on StackOverflow: [Setting application info in a Qt executable file on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784697/setting-application-info-in-qt)

(Again, assuming this is what you're looking for.)