# How to build Qt App, which could show own properties like "Version", "Company Name", "Product Name", etc.?

Tags: qt, properties, resources, version, exe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Setting application info in Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784697/setting-application-info-in-qt)

I create a rc-file.
It was built to res with correct content.
But final exe-file hasn't a tab Version in it's properties.
What I should to do to make this tab visible?

Comment: If the tab is not visible you did something wrong check out the question witch is similar to yours to get it working

Comment: I can't find same questions, please link them to me ...

Comment: Already found, it works, thanks.