# Setting Application Information in Qt

Tags: qt, resources

I have now pretty much finished my application in Qt. I want to deploy it and among other things I would like to set the application information when someone right clicks the executable file and looks at the details.

The best source of information I found was this link: [Setting application info in a Qt executable file on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784697/setting-application-info-in-qt)

However, in Qt5, after creating a .qrc file and a prefix, I couldn't get it to work. If the .qrc file is edited outside of Qt, an unknown error always occurs when opening it inside Qt.

Can anybody please provide me with an working example? The way it's shown in the link above is exactly what I would like to do.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note that Windows resource files (.rc) have nothing to do with Qt's resource files (.qrc).

Comment: Did you try the second answer?

Comment: @Frank Osterfeld: No. What I wanted was exactly what was contained in the first answer. Have one place in my code (.h file) where I can change the info and see it changed everywhere in my application. Also, I didn't tried because I didn't understood how to setup the resource file for it.

Answer (score 1):

Just create file "resources.rc" with Qt Creator "File"->"New File of Project.."->"General"->"Text file" or with any text editor in your project folder with this context:

```
IDI_ICON1   ICON    DISCARDABLE "res/app.ico"

#include <windows.h>
#include "version.h"

VS_VERSION_INFO VERSIONINFO
FILEVERSION     VER_FILEVERSION
PRODUCTVERSION  VER_PRODUCTVERSION
BEGIN
    BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        BLOCK "040904E4"
        BEGIN
            VALUE "CompanyName",        VER_COMPANYNAME_STR
            VALUE "FileDescription",    VER_FILEDESCRIPTION_STR
            VALUE "FileVersion",        VER_FILEVERSION_STR
            VALUE "InternalName",       VER_INTERNALNAME_STR
            VALUE "LegalCopyright",     VER_LEGALCOPYRIGHT_STR
            VALUE "LegalTrademarks1",   VER_LEGALTRADEMARKS1_STR
            VALUE "LegalTrademarks2",   VER_LEGALTRADEMARKS2_STR
            VALUE "OriginalFilename",   VER_ORIGINALFILENAME_STR
            VALUE "ProductName",        VER_PRODUCTNAME_STR
            VALUE "ProductVersion",     VER_PRODUCTVERSION_STR
        END
    END

    BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        VALUE "Translation", 0x409, 1252
    END
END
```

You should also have header file "version.h" in your project:

```
#ifndef VERSION_H
#define VERSION_H

#define VER_FILEVERSION             1,0,0,0
#define VER_FILEVERSION_STR         "1.0.0.0\0"

#define VER_PRODUCTVERSION          1,0,0,0
#define VER_PRODUCTVERSION_STR      "1.0\0"

#define VER_COMPANYNAME_STR         "Your Organization"
#define VER_FILEDESCRIPTION_STR     "CoolApplication"
#define VER_INTERNALNAME_STR        "CoolApplication"
#define VER_LEGALCOPYRIGHT_STR      "Copyright © 2010 Your Organization"
#define VER_LEGALTRADEMARKS1_STR    "All Rights Reserved"
#define VER_LEGALTRADEMARKS2_STR    VER_LEGALTRADEMARKS1_STR
#define VER_ORIGINALFILENAME_STR    "coolapplication.exe"
#define VER_PRODUCTNAME_STR         "CoolApplication"

#define VER_COMPANYDOMAIN_STR       "example.org"

#endif // VERSION_H
```

Then in your *.pro file add

```
RC_FILE = file_prop_detail.rc
```

That is all. This aproach worked for me with Qt 5.4.