# Qt Gui Application icon setup

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, windows-7, qt5.5

I want to setup an icon for my qt gui application , and followed the steps listed below:

```
 1. create an ICO file bitmap That contains the icon image.
 2. Store the ICO file in app's source code directory.
 3. create a text file and added these lines "IDI_ICON1 ICON DISCARDABLE
 4. myicon.ico" and saved it as "myicon.rc".
 5. and added these lines in my .pro file "RC_FILE = MYICON.RC"
```

but it is giving this error:

> mingw32-make[1]: *** No rule to make target '../Test/myicon.rc',
>   needed by 'debug/myicon_res.o'.  Stop. mingw32-make: *** [debug] Error
>   2 02:15:41: The process "C:\TDM-GCC-32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited
>   with code 2. Error while building/deploying project Test (kit:
>   Desktop) When executing step 'Make'

Comment: This is meant for visual studio.

Comment: no, I am using Qt creater

Comment: Yes, but Qt creator is not a compiler in itself, it needs a compiler to do its work.

Comment: Yes i know that buddy, i am using MinGW (x86 32bit), as i am using 32bit system.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is probably that you are including `myicon.rc` as a regular file, and it is listed as a source file.  It should not be listed there nor under headers, because it isn't going through the normal compiler.  You do need to list it as `RC_FILE = myapp.rc`.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#rc-file

Note that `ICON` in .pro is only used on mac.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#icon

I've included sample code for how I typically handle my `rc` file, a version file, and how it gets used in `main.cpp` and in the `.pro` file.

This should work in Qt Creator and Visual Studio.

Here are the files I use when I am doing versioning and icons in windows:

myapp.rc

```
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784697/setting-application-info-in-qt
#include <windows.h>
#include "version.h"

// if you needed to maintain two different icons for your app, you could
// switch here using a #ifdef and #else
#define MYICON "my_icon.ico"

IDI_ICON1               ICON    DISCARDABLE     MYICON

VS_VERSION_INFO VERSIONINFO
FILEVERSION     VER_FILEVERSION
PRODUCTVERSION  VER_PRODUCTVERSION
BEGIN
    BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        BLOCK "040904E4"
        BEGIN
            VALUE "CompanyName",        VER_COMPANYNAME_STR
            VALUE "FileDescription",    VER_FILEDESCRIPTION_STR
            VALUE "FileVersion",        VER_FILEVERSION_STR
            VALUE "InternalName",       VER_INTERNALNAME_STR
            VALUE "LegalCopyright",     VER_LEGALCOPYRIGHT_STR
            VALUE "LegalTrademarks1",   VER_LEGALTRADEMARKS1_STR
            VALUE "LegalTrademarks2",   VER_LEGALTRADEMARKS2_STR
            VALUE "OriginalFilename",   VER_ORIGINALFILENAME_STR
            VALUE "ProductName",        VER_PRODUCTNAME_STR
            VALUE "ProductVersion",     VER_PRODUCTVERSION_STR
        END
    END

    BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        VALUE "Translation", 0x409, 1252
    END
END
```

version.h

```
#ifndef VERSION_H
#define VERSION_H

#define VER_FILEVERSION             0,1,0,0
#define VER_FILEVERSION_STR         "0.1.0.0\0"

#define VER_PRODUCTVERSION          15,07,01,50
#define VER_PRODUCTVERSION_STR      "15.07.01.50"

#define VER_COMPANYNAME_STR         "MySoft"
#define VER_FILEDESCRIPTION_STR     "Star Runner"

#define VER_INTERNALNAME_STR        "Star Runner"
#define VER_LEGALCOPYRIGHT_STR      "Copyright © MySoft"
#define VER_LEGALTRADEMARKS1_STR    "All Rights Reserved"
#define VER_LEGALTRADEMARKS2_STR    VER_LEGALTRADEMARKS1_STR
#define VER_ORIGINALFILENAME_STR    "star_runner.exe"
#define VER_PRODUCTNAME_STR         "Star Runner"

#define VER_COMPANYDOMAIN_STR       "mysoft.com"

#endif // VERSION_H
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "version.h"
#include <QSettings>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    a.setApplicationName(VER_PRODUCTNAME_STR);
    a.setOrganizationName(VER_COMPANYNAME_STR);
    a.setOrganizationDomain(VER_COMPANYDOMAIN_STR);
    a.setApplicationDisplayName(VER_PRODUCTNAME_STR);
    QSettings::setDefaultFormat(QSettings::IniFormat);

    // Create the widget or main window here

    return a.exec();
}
```

star_runner.pro

```
# all sorts of other things like SOURCES and HEADERS and FORMS, etc.
# ...

win32 {
    # DEFINES -= UNICODE
    RC_FILE += myapp.rc
}

macx {
    ICON = my_icon.icns
}

OTHER_FILES += \
    my_icon.ico \
    my_icon.icns \
    myapp.rc
```

And lastly when creating icons, I usually use Gimp, making them at least 256x256 and then exporting them at different sizes using [Phoca Save Icons](http://registry.gimp.org/node/12763). Other times I'll just make an png and then use something from [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=png%20to%20ico).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But getting the same error, and "mingw32-make[1]: *** No rule to make target '../Test/myicon.rc', needed by 'release/myicon_res.o'.  Stop."      What is that mean??

Comment: I guess there is some problem in qt creater kit while deploying/building the project. any suggestions???

Comment: Try a build clean, and deleting the Make.release and the Make.deploy files.  That usually fixes some lingering problems after changing the .pro file.

Comment: now one more error , release is not happening giving error "The program has unexpectedly finished",   if i did not involve the icon and all that stuff, the program is building successfully, and i am still getting that "icon" error ,tried lot of stuffs already.  :(

Comment: I did that many times "Try a build clean, and deleting the Make.release and the Make.deploy files. That usually fixes some lingering problems after changing the .pro file."

Answer (score 0):

Mingw does not know how to handle a .rc file.

See: http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MS_resource_compiler

Comment: So i have to change my compiler, is that what you mean. ?? Can you just elaborate a little bit, that might can help.

Comment: Either you change your compiler, or use a tool like windres like in the page i linked.