# Adding the resources.rc file info the project

Tags: c++, qt, resources

I want to add information about my App by adding resources.rc file info my project.

I used this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3323786/6788868

But after that I'm getting

> "When writing output to: invalid argument"

in resources.rc file.

I think that I might be adding this rc file in wrong way: right click on project -> add new... -> General -> Empty file -> resources.rc

All I did was creating this rc file and version.h file as a header file, and pasting the content from answer above.

This error exists after

```
#include "version.h"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your using Qt creator why not add this to your projects .pro file like the second answer on that post said.

```
VERSION = 0.4.0.1
QMAKE_TARGET_COMPANY = company
QMAKE_TARGET_PRODUCT = product
QMAKE_TARGET_DESCRIPTION = description
QMAKE_TARGET_COPYRIGHT = copyright
```

Comment: This will also work, but I wanna solve this problem with adding rc file into project. I don't know whats the reason causing this error. Most of times I'm getting "Error 1"

Comment: did you add version.h to the project?

Comment: Are you on windows and are you able to post all relevant file pertaining to the error (.pro, .rc, version.h)

Comment: thank you for your attention, problem is solved now. I had bad icon path - "Program Files" - now I know I cant add spaces there.
Does anyone know how I can write Program Files in path like that: "C:/Program Files/.."?