# How to add details to files created by code?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

i am using c++ in QT-Creator 4.0.1.

I want to add custom Details to a file i created in code, and i have no clue how i can do this.

[Something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jjyrp.png)

Comment: Have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/a/3323786/6351120 ?

Comment: Files are arrays of bytes. There are file format specifications. In your case that would be the PNG file format. Read the PNG specification and see how those field are organized. Then create / insert accordingly.

Comment: Firstly read about metadata of specific file type(extension).

Comment: Which "details" are missing for the files you created?

Comment: The answer of @bhazero025 points to hits the jackpot probably. I'm using same approach in my project. Add `RC_FILE` in project and point to a resource file with proper format/detail description. Works like a charm.