# Qt - Change name of app in process (without extension)

Tags: windows, qt, process, exe, target

How to change name of app, that will be shown in processes. It should be without ".exe" at the end.

I know that:

```
TARGET = CLICK_IT
```

It works to change app name, but there is .exe. How to this without .exe?

This is what i mean (I want it **like** Google Chrome):

[image]

Comment: By "shown in processes" what exactly do you mean? The list of processes in some process manager application? This sounds like and X-Y problem to me, so what’s the underlying problem you’re trying to solve? On Windows an executable file is pretty much required to have the .exe extension. Almost everything in the system relies on that extension to detect executable files. And just to make sure: we *are* talking about Windows, aren’t we?

Comment: This comes from the VERSIONINFO resource, FileDescription property.  [This Q+A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784697/setting-application-info-in-a-qt-executable-file-on-windows) talks about adding one in a Qt project.

Comment: It works. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting application info in a Qt executable file on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784697/setting-application-info-in-a-qt-executable-file-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
QMAKE_TARGET_DESCRIPTION = CLICK_IT
```